# Filled oil with 10L - the car now has problems with the engine cutting out or badly vibrating the car

Tags: engine, oil-change

My husband added 5L of oil to the car, he was told to add another 5L.  Now the car makes a very loud sound almost like a vacuum. The car switches itself off when started.

Speed picks up very slowly (if at all) and fuel consumption has increased greatly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We need to know the car make, model, year and (preferably) engine size to know by how much the engine has been overfilled. Also, as vini_i says, have the excess oil drained as soon as possible and don't continue driving it in its present state.

Comment: Did you have to add another 5L because it became low on oil even after adding the first 5L?

Comment: As Zaid stated, this is *very* dependent upon what is *supposed* to be put into the engine. If it is only supposed to have 5L in the crank case, you are most likely hitting sitting oil with the crankshaft which can cause *extreme damage* very quickly to the engine. Getting this information is tantamount to getting you a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

10 litres of oil is an immense amount for the average car. The way I read your statement, your husband added 5+5 litres of oil to your car, without even previously removing the oil that was already in.

Fisrt of all, find out how much oil your car actually needs. Then drain the engine and refill with the appropriate amount, as already stated.

As in my view the possibility of engine damage isn't negligible, it'd be better to actually get the car towed to a shop, get them to change the oil and check for problems.

Please bear in mind that to get better answers you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You did not state make model and year of car. Most average cars hold somewhere between 4 and 6 liters of oil. 10 liters is overfilling the oil even if the engine was completely empty. Don't keep trying to start the car. Drain out the oil that is in the car. Fill the oil back up with the correct amount. Hope that the engine is not damaged.

Comment: Again, this number depends on the engine model. For example, a W12 *needs* 13.5 L